# iFramed site with adsense "leaking" page views

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, adsense

I've been searching around for a while now but I can't seem to find a solution to my issue.
I'm trying to place a site that I own inside an iframe on one of my other sites and I'm constantly running into the issue where page views in adsense statistics count towards the site that contains the iframe code and not the site that has the actual ads placed on it.

The code that I'm using is nothing special:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" style="position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe>
```

I need to keep the position fixed and the width and height as it is, running the iframe sandboxed is not an option.

Is there any way to prevent these views from occurring on the site that contains the iframe and keep them entirely on the page that has the actual ads on it?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the amount of leaked views is very small: for every 1500 page views there are roughly 7-8 leaks.

Also like I mentioned in a post below:
The domain that contains the iframe code has no ads on it whatsoever and I don't use analytics. In fact I even tried removing everything from the page which contains the iframe and leaving it totally empty (with only basic html code and the iframe) and the issue was still there.

Comment: Move the analytics code to the page in the iframe, instead of the outer page.

Comment: I dont understand your question: when you load the outer page, it loads the inner iframe page as well. So you should see adsense statistics for both the pages.

Comment: I probably didn't clarify properly. The domain that contains the iframe code has no ads on it whatsoever and I don't use analytics. In fact I even tried removing everything from the page which contains the iframe and leaving it totally empty (with only basic html code and the iframe) and the issue was still there.